# Error TS2345: Argument of type '{ Item: object[]; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ x: any; y: any; z: any; a: any; }'

Tags: angular, typescript, destructuring

I am using type Destructuring in the function parameter, code works fine, but will get error in the console.

> error TS2345: Argument of type '{ Item: object[]; }' is not assignable
>   to parameter of type '{ x: any; y: any; z: any; a: any; }'.

Want to get rid of this and really want to know the root cause 
list is array of objects

```
   for (const item of list) {
       calcTotal({item });
   }

   calcTotal( {x, y, z, a} ) {
       new += x;
       current += y;
       amount += z;
       currntAmount += a;
   }
```

Comment: This error told your "item" which is on your for loop is Array. It must be a object.

Comment: @nevzatopcu Thanks, yes that's what i also understood, and as mentioned that code works fine, so am not sure what should i do to get rid of this console error.As am looping over array of object so item  is actually a object that's why there is not run time error;;

Comment: Try to console log and paste your "item" there. I think there is a nested arrays.

Comment: {name: "abc", flags: Array(0), allocation: 211810.09687, Pct: 96.917179, New: 148267.0684716697, …}
allocation: 211810.09687
allocationMaxPct: 96.917179
allocationMinPct: 0
allocationNew: 148267.0684716697
allocationNewPct: 67.8420253
allocationPct: 96.917179
allocationRec: 148267.067809
allocationRecMaxPct: null
allocationRecMinPct: null
allocationRecPct: 67.8420253
assets: []
classifications: (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
flags: []
hardMax: 96.917179
hardmax: undefined
locked: undefined
maxFromCalculator: 96.917179
minFromCalculator: 0
name: "Long Term Value"
__proto__: Object

Comment: typeof approach
"object"

Comment: Try to do following changes on your loop { if((item instanceof Object) calcTotal(item); }  check is it object and remove curly parentheses.